# psql how to drop current database

Tags: postgresql

Trying to drop the primary database "foo", I get the error

> ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database

Whats the right way to drop the primary psql database?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected

Comment: @MitchWheat that question is marked as off topic (so I coudln't post a relevant-to-seo answer), and doesn't include anything about the target database being current database. - also fair ot point out dba stackex may have good resources

Comment: The fact that the linked question was marked as off-topic makes it likely this is also.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's what the database `postgres` is there for.

Connect to it to drop your database.

Comment: This is the best answer by far. Thanks :)

Comment: Plus: 1. Disconnect the database you want to drop 2. Drop it via drop database myDatabase

Comment: This is the only correct answer to do it with psql

Comment: You cannot drop a database by using a session of the same database in some versions of PostgreSQL.  Connect to another database and then run command DROP DATABASE DB;

Comment: @MacGyver Right, that's what my answer recommends. Unless you need to drop the `postgres` database, then you have to connect to a different database. But `postgres` is typically left empty, and you shouldn't feel a need to drop it.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting you.  I upvoted you on another to make up for it.

Comment: @MacGyver No problem, these are just brownie points anyway. You should be able to un-downvote however.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know about this `postgres` empty database. I've struggled to find documentation about it though, why / when / how does this database get created? Is it generated when Postgresql is installed on the server?

Comment: @benj-p It is created when you create the database cluster with `initdb`.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new database to log into while you drop the original one - I guess?

```
create database _;
(relog with -d _ )
drop database dbname;
create database dbname;
(relog)
drop database _;
```

Comment: creating a new database is definitely unnecessary extra steps. connect directly to an internal database like `postgres`

Comment: off the top of my head, i vaguely recall the target database to drop being `postures`; even in that case, template0 might exist? well in any case, if a temporary db is created it will exist regardless of the target db to operate on. cheers

Comment: idk what your `postures` database is, but `postgres` database _always_ exists. there is no need to create a new temporary database just to drop a database. switch to `postgres` and drop the database. your method _forces_ you to create a new one, or keep a temporary one

Comment: oh excuse the typo, "the target database to drop being `postgres`" (the one that will always exist), in my experiments, this database did appear to tolerate being dropped and did not exist after it was dropped. this comment recited from older memory